# Why is my Windows CE device unable to successfully invoke my server's REST methods?

Tags: c#, rest, http-status-code-503, network-traffic, ppp

This is related/sort of a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27303183/how-can-i-determine-which-packet-in-wireshark-corresponds-to-what-i-sent-via-pos) but contains more and more specific information.

I have a REST app running on my PC. I need to call some of the methods on the server from a handheld WindowsCE device that uses the compact framework.

I can contact the server's methods from Postman, so it's not a problem that way. In Postman, I use:

```
http://localhost:21609/api/inventory/sendXML/duckbill/platypus/bloo
```

...and with this I reach the breakpoint in this REST method on my server app:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/inventory/sendxml/{userId}/{pwd}/{filename}")]
public async Task SendInventoryXML(String userId, String pwd, String fileName)
```

However, although using "PPP_PEER" is the way to contact the PC from the handheld device (127.0.0.1 doesn't fly, because the handheld sees that as being itself, and commits egregious acts of cannibalism when trying to contact that address) - as can be seen by this TCP code that does work from the handheld device:

```
string pingString = "PING|";
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("PPP_PEER", 7727);
try
{
    try
    {
        Stream s = client.GetStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s) { AutoFlush = true };
        String response = String.Empty;

        if (firstRecord)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(pingString);
            . . .
```

...trying to use PPP_PEER to call the REST method fails.

Here is the code I use to try to do that:

```
    //HHSConsts
    public static string BASE_REST_URL = "http://PPP_PEER:21609/api/";

    . . .

    //frmMain
    private void SendInventories()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (String tblname in listBoxWork.Items)
            {
                String xmlData = hhsdbutils.GetINVDataAsXMLFromTable(tblname, fileName);
                String uri = String.Format("{0}inventory/sendXML/duckbill/platypus/{1}",
HHSConsts.BASE_REST_URL, fileName);
                fileXferImp = HHSConsts.GetFileTransferMethodology();
                fileXferImp.SendDataContentsAsXML(uri, xmlData, tblname);
                . . .

// FileXferREST.cs
public void SendDataContentsAsXML(String destinationPath, String data, String fileName, 
String siteNumber, bool firstRecord, bool lastRecord)
{
    SendHTTPRequestNoCredentials(destinationPath, HttpMethods.POST, data, "application/xml"); 
}

public static HttpWebRequest SendHTTPRequestNoCredentials(string uri, HttpMethods method, 
string data, string contentType)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    try
    {
        request.Method = Enum.ToObject(typeof(HttpMethods), method).ToString();
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).Accept = contentType;
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).KeepAlive = false;
        ((HttpWebRequest)request).ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

        if (method != HttpMethods.GET && method != HttpMethods.DELETE)
        {
            byte[] arrData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            request.ContentLength = arrData.Length;
            using (Stream oS = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                oS.Write(arrData, 0, arrData.Length);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            request.ContentLength = 0;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException webex)
    {
        HttpWebResponse hwr = (HttpWebResponse)webex.Response;
        HttpStatusCode hsc = hwr.StatusCode;
        String webExMsgAndStatusCode = String.Format("{0} Status code == {1}", webex.Message, 
hsc.ToString());
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(String.Format("From 
FileXferREST.SendHTTPRequestNoCredentials: {0}", webExMsgAndStatusCode));
    }
    return request as HttpWebRequest;
}
```

No exception is thrown; it simply doens't work.

When attempting this call, I run rawcap to capture the packages being sent over the network with these command line args:

```
rawcap 127.0.0.1 [fileName].pcap
```

I then open the .pcap file in Wireshark, search for "21609" and get this TCP stream:

[image]

...I added the screen shot above to show the red/blue coloration for the request/response, but here is the entire rawcap/Wireshark conversation involving port 21609:

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

POST /api//inventory/sendXML/duckbill/platypus/INV_3_20090307181658000.xml HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: application/xml
Accept: application/xml
Connection: Close
Content-Length: 388
Host: ppp_peer:21609

112209003343742SOME DESC2.2testVendorID]6161.51.995.58HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpccHJvamVjdFxnaXRcQ1N0b3JlXEhIUy5BUElcYXBpXGludmVudG9yeVxzZW5kWE1MXGR1Y2tiaWxsXHBsYXR5cHVzXElOVl8zXzIwMDkwMzA3MTgxNjU4MDAwLnhtbA==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 18 Dec 2014 17:23:01 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 5016

IIS 8.0 Detailed Error - 404.0 - Not Found

#### HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. 
 
 
 Most likely causes:

  .
- The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
  .
- The URL contains a typographical error.
  .
- A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

Things you can try:

  .
- Create the content on the Web server.
  .
- Review the browser URL.
  .
- Check the failed request tracing log and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information, click [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439).

Detailed Error Information: 
   
    
    Module   IIS Web Core 
    Notification   MapRequestHandler 
    Handler   StaticFile 
    Error Code   0x80070002 

    
   
   
    
    Requested URL   http://ppp_peer:21609/api/inventory/sendXML/duckbill/platypus/INV_3_20090307181658000.xml 
    Physical Path   C:\project\git\CStore\HHS.API\api\inventory\sendXML\duckbill\platypus\INV_3_20090307181658000.xml 
    Logon Method   Anonymous 
    Logon User   Anonymous 
    Request Tracing Directory   C:\Users\clay\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\HHS.API 
    
    
   
  
 

 
 More Information: 
  This error means that the file or directory does not exist on the server. Create the file or directory and try the request again.

[View more information »](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&IIS70Error=404,0,0x80070002,7601)

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

So to recap, "PPP_PEER" does work as a way for the handheld device to describe/contact the PC (it works with the TCP code), and the REST method is reachable from another process (such as Postman), but trying to call the method using PPP_PEER from the handheld device fail with the "404.0 - Not Found" error.

Why?

### UPDATE

When I replace "PPP_PEER" with the machine name of the PC, the error changes from "404 - Not Found" to "503 - Service Unavailable":

[image]

But that is a bit of a rompecabeza, because the service *is* obviously available, as it is running and its breakpoint is hit when I call it from Postman.

### UPDATE 2

Now this is odd: If I use the full machine name instead of just the "truncated" name, the error goes back to being 404 instead of 503:

[image]

So if I use PPP_PEER as the host name, I get a 404; if I use shannon2, I get a 503; if I use shannon2.sscs.ad, I again get 404. Should I blame this on Tim Berners-Lee, Al Gore, Andy Warhol, or someone else?

SO...those are my results on trying to follow Eric Law's first suggestion; there are two others, but: what would I edit the Host header *to* that might make a difference? Or overwrite it to *what*?

Comment: My first assumption is that while `PPP_PEER` hits the proper TCP/IP endpoint, the `Host` header on that request is rejected as it isn't a hostname the server is configured to respond to. You could try using the machine's public hostname in the URL, or edit the `Host` header with Fiddler, or possibly even manually overwrite it from the client API.

Comment: Does calling `http://shannon2.sscs.ad:21609/api/inventory/sendXML/duckbill/platypus/bloo` work from Postman on your PC? Is the http site binding in for *:21609 (i.e. all addresses)?

Comment: @ma499: Yes, that works via Postman.

Comment: @ma499: However, as noted above, "if I use shannon2.sscs.ad, I again get 404"

Comment: With your first pcap trace it response with server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0 so obviously the request was hitting your IIS service rather than your Visual Studio built in WebServer.

Comment: Your second trace response with Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0. I think this hit the right port but you don't have visual studio in debug

Comment: @TienDinh: Build > Configuration Manager... does show the "Active solution configuration" to be Debug (top dropdowns) and the "Project contexts" (grid) to show only one Configuration, which is "Debug" with both Build and Deploy checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if the basic problem is trying to access a "server" app running locally on my PC (even though the handheld != the PC, it is "sort of" the same thing, after a fashion).

Now that the server app is running on a different machine on the network altogether, I'm able to hit it; albeit not yet totally unexceptionally, as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642714/how-can-i-establish-a-secure-channel-for-ssl-tls-from-a-handheld-device).