# Consuming SSL SOAP Service, could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

I'm working on a `Windows Mobile 6.5 Pro` application, using `.NET Compact Edition 3.5`.

I'm able to contact the standard web service (not using SSL), but `HTTPS` won't go through. I've attempted to add another Web reference ; this one pointing to the HTTPS version. I was assuming it would generate the proper code for SSL, but nothing.

Every time I attempt to communicate with the service via code I get the following:

> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. Could
>   not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS.

**I tested the same code on a `.NET 4.5` console app and I was able to successfully reach the HTTPS Web service** and get back XML response without issues.

**It appears that the generated Web Refence on VS2008 for HTTPS is missing something?**

There's not much code to show here besides the auto-generated code that VS2008 produces when you add a new Web Reference.

**UPDATE 1:**
I've been following this post which appears to be the same issue i'm encountering but sadly I don't think it was resolved.
[How can I establish a secure channel for SSL/TLS from a handheld device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642714/how-can-i-establish-a-secure-channel-for-ssl-tls-from-a-handheld-device)

**UPDATE 2:**
After more research, Windows Mobile 6.5 Pro only appears to support TLS v1.0 while the SOAP Service I was attempting to communicate with is v1.2 (latest).

A bit on TLS and SSL: [Here](https://www.wolfssl.com/wolfSSL/Blog/Entries/2010/10/7_Differences_between_SSL_and_TLS_Protocol_Versions.html).

**WS 2003** had SSL 2.0/3.0 and TLS 1.0 enabled by default. The default installation did not support AES ciphers – but support could be added through a hotfix.

**WS 2008** also had SSL 2.0/3.0 and TLS 1.0 enabled by default, but improved the cryptographic support with new AES cipher suites.

**WS 2008 R2** introduced TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2, but they were disabled by default.

**WS 2012** takes us a step further with TLS 1.2 enabled by default.