# Problems with REST HTTPS request on WinCE

Tags: vb.net, https, compact-framework, windows-ce, webrequest

I'm porting a vb.net HTTPS client application on WinCE60 CF35: bsically it needs to send HTTPS REST requests to a server.

I started development on a Win10 desktop and there I have no problems (VS2015 - NET35).

When I run on WinCE I receive an exception when I send the webrequest: the system says that it does not have the error message, but I see the status = 10 = SecureChannelFailure.

The code is the following:

```
Private Function SendGetRequest(cmd As String) As Boolean

    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(m_baseUrl + cmd)

    request.Method = "GET"
    request.Timeout = m_timeout
    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + m_authInfo)
    '
    Dim dataStream As Stream
    '
    Try
        Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
        m_statusCode = CType(response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode

        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
        ...
```

On the server side I don't receive anything. So, I tryed to sniff using Wireshark and I see the following:

[image: Sniff]
In my understanding the client (.113) sends a RESET, but I don't know why ..

PS: if I build a HTTP request I receive response.

Comment: I substituted the standard calls with the ones by Rebex. This library can generate a log where I found: 2017-07-14 16:27:44 INFO HttpRequest(1)[89589158] TLS: Certificate verification status: RootNotTrusted, CnNotMatch (32)

Comment: For the moment I solved with the Rebex lib adding to my source code the line: client.Settings.SslAcceptAllCertificates = True  Now I'd like to understand if the problem on CF35 was on TLS version, SHA version or whatever ..

Answer (score 1):

Multiple potential issues here:

- Based on the error message, the most likely problem: The CE device may be missing a root certificate, or the root certificate may be expired or revoked, and therefore Windows CE is unable to verify the server certificate. If your CE device has a UI, open the Certificates applet in the Control Panel to verify that the required root certificate is installed and valid
- .NET CF does not support SHA-2 based certificates (see answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986714/wince-6-smart-device-could-not-establish-secure-channel-for-ssl-tls-error)). Mentioning this because it's the next problem you are likely to run into, once the root cert is in place
- Windows CE often sends RST to close TCP connections. Not pretty, but probably unrelated to the HTTPS problem you're seeing (as far as I understand the rationale is this is faster than having both sides send FIN/ACK)